# DisplayObjects as animation frames? AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

**How can I use displayObjects as animation frames?**
I have six symbols in my library I want to animate with a timer. The advantage would be the ability to change the speed of the animations, and the elimination of the messy timeline.

The only drawback is the initial setup of the objects in the library. I've tried switch/case design patterns, visible=true, and z-depth, but I can't get it to work properly. Any answers?

```
//setup code
var timer:Timer = new Timer(100, 20);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
function countdown(event:TimerEvent) {
    myText.text = String(0 + timer.currentCount);
}
timer.start();

var frame1:Frame1 = new Frame1;
addChild(frame1);
//frame1.visible = false

var frame2:Frame2 = new Frame2;
addChild(frame2);
//frame1.visible = false

var frame3:Frame3 = new Frame3;
addChild(frame3);
//frame1.visible = false

var frame4:Frame4 = new Frame4;
addChild(frame4);
//frame1.visible = false

var frame5:Frame5 = new Frame5;
addChild(frame5);
//frame1.visible = false

var frame6:Frame6 = new Frame6;
addChild(frame6);
//frame1.visible = false
```

Comment: I'm aware the "timeline" is usually frowned upon in the flash world, especially by newcomers. It can certainly get messy when you start to sprinkle code all over. But it seems like you're fighting against how flash works here. If you really need to change animation speed at runtime, this could be an option (though you can control the timeline playhead by code too). If you can't or don't want to use the Flash IDE, this is the way to go. But if you don't, you're kind of missing the whole point of the timeline. Let artists / designers do what they know better, with the tools their familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. This is written for readability, not performance or expandability, but should get you on the right track.

```
var frames:Array = [
    new Frame1(),
    new Frame2(),
    new Frame3(),
    new Frame4(),
    new Frame5(),
    new Frame6()
];

for each (var frame:Sprite in frames) {
    addChild(frame);
}

var timer:Timer = new Timer(100);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
function countdown(event:TimerEvent) {
    myText.text = String(0 + timer.currentCount);
    var currentFrame:int = timer.currentCount % frames.length;
    for (var i:int = 0; i < frames.length; ++i) {
        frames[i].visible = (i == currentFrame);
    }
}
timer.start();
```